# How to arrange three lists in such a way that the sum of corresponding elements if greater then appear first?

Tags: python, list

I am new in python. I have three lists of floats of same length. The numbers are randomly distributed in all lists. But the positions of elements in one list corresponds to the other elements of the same positions in other lists. Let's say the lists are,

`a=[1,5,3,2,4]
b=[20,30,50,40,10]
c=[400,500,100,300,200]`

Now, elements of same positions in these three lists correspond each other. Like 1, 20 and 400 correspond each other; 3, 50 and 100 correspond each other and so on.
I have to arrange the numbers in such a way that for any position i of these three lists if the sum of the corresponding numbers are greater then those three numbers should appear first in the lists. Like,

`e=[500, 400, 300, 200, 100]
f=[30,20,40,10,50]
g=[5,1,2,4,3]`

So the positions of corresponding numbers have changed altogether. Or their correspondence MUST NOT BREAK. As a beginner I have tried in many ways but all in vain. Please help me.

Comment: list of floats. These are lists of ints.

Comment: Please post what you have tried, including the full text of any errors or tracebacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to the original question (pre edit)

Try this.

```
a=[1,5,3,2,4]
b=[20,30,50,40,10]
c=[400,500,100,300,200]

x = sorted(zip(a,b,c), key=lambda x: sum(x), reverse=True)

e, f, g = map(list, zip(*x))

print e
print f
print g
```

Output

```
[5, 1, 2, 4, 3]
[30, 20, 40, 10, 50]
[500, 400, 300, 200, 100]
```

Use `zip` to create a list of `tuples`, then sort them using their sum as the key, reversed so the largest sum is first. If you are using python 2.7 you could use `izip` instead of `zip` to somewhat reduce the memory burden with large lists but the full sorted list still needs to be created. In python 3 `zip` is equivalent of 2.7's `izip`.

The `sorted` function will return you list of tuples, so you want to now turn them back into your original 3 list format. The fastest and cleanest way to do this (courtesy of @JohnClements).

```
e, f, g = map(list, zip(*x))
```

To explain this statement, remembering that x is a list of `tuples` each of length 3.

- First pass zip the unpacked `tuples` from x (using expression `*x`). This results in a new list containing 3 `tuples`. The first `tuple` contains all the first elements from the tuples in x, the second `tuple` contains all the second elements from x and so on.
- Now you have a list of `tuples`, but we want our iterable to contain `lists`, so `map` is the correct function to use to do the conversion. It will be fast as its performing the conversion in native c code. The result is a `list` of `list`s.
- finally we can unpack the `list` of `lists` to 3 separate list variables `e`, `f` and `g`.

If you require more detailed understanding of the code I suggest you print the output at intermediate stages.

Comment: Instead of the 3 list comps - you can use `j, k, l = map(list, zip(*x))` instead

Comment: @JonClements thanks I though that could be improved. I only didnt do it in one loop using 3 lists as it was more code.

Comment: @JonClements But it is not working again. Again idle "not responding"; numpy correspondence may help me...

Comment: Hi @VikramadityaMondal moving goal posts! I dont have time to revise my answer but perhaps a generator is the best solution, to avoid having actually creating whole lists in memory.

Comment: @Vikram I dont think JonClements was suggesting how to make my answer work with your updated requirements, he was simply suggesting  way to avoid running 3 loops when turning the list of tuples back to the 3 lists.

Comment: @PaulRooney but anyway generator will not help me, that text file contains some special observational data I need to plot in PLplot. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Do you want me to add explanation in my answer for that line?

Comment: @PaulRooney yes that will be better.

Comment: @PaulRooney in this case we are comparing the sum of the elements. But if that has to done in a slightly complex way, like, multiplying any three(fixed and constant) numbers with those list elements and then adding them and then based upon this, sorting the previous list; I have tried this way, lambda x: 1.2*a[x]+0.2*b[x]+0.7*c[x]. But it is showing error, "too many indices "

Comment: That's a separate question

Comment: @PaulRooney Should I ask this separately?

Comment: @PaulRooney okay now that question is on hold. can you tell me why that didn't work as I told previously, please?

Comment: Try `lambda x: 1.2*x[0] + 0.2*x[1] + 0.7*x[2]`. Remember that only x is visible inside the lambda (not a,b, or c). Also that x is a tuple of length 3 so you can access its members by index 0, 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the values of lists as:

```
a=[1,5,3,2,4]
b=[20,30,50,40,10]
c=[400,500,100,300,200]

x = sorted(range(len(a)), key = lambda x:a[x]+b[x]+c[x], reverse = True)

print "\n".join([" ".join([str(j[i]) for i in x])for j in [a, b, c]])

>>> 5 1 2 4 3
    30 20 40 10 50
    500 400 300 200 100
```

Comment: I need lists as end product. But printed outputs are not iterable. how to get three lists?